# A storage class is not allowed in an explicit specialization

Tags: c++, gcc

I have the following code in a header file that does not belong to a class:

```
template<typename Foo> static const Compl<Foo,bar> *foobar (const FBTYPE &x);

template<> static const Compl<typea,bar> *foobar<typea>(const FBTYPE &x) {
    return x.funcA();
}

template<> static const Compl<typeb,bar> *foobar<typeb>(const FBTYPE &x) {
    return x.funcB();
}
```

The code compiles just fine with older GCC versions but in newer ones I get this error message:

```
rsvt.h(672): error #3503: a storage class is not allowed in an explicit specialization
  template<> static const Compl<typea,bar> *foobar<typea>(const FBTYPE &x) {
             ^
```

Any idea why it works with older versions of GCC but not with newer ones? Also, how can I get it to work with GCC 5?

Comment: Why are you using `static` with free functions?

Comment: In any case, these are templates; why `static`? Make them `inline`.

Comment: I can't think of any reason to use `static` with a function template in a header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is in the following quote which is now in the C++ standard: [`[dcl.stc]/p1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.stc#1)

> A storage-class-specifier other than thread_local shall not be specified in an explicit specialization

Comment: I think you should add [\[temp\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#4) to your answer.